# sed replaces string by line break but not the other way around

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace line breaks, for which I *want* to use `sed` (please do not suggest alternative tools). To replace a line break by a string I am trying

```
sed 's/\n/string/g'
```

which does *not* work, at least on my system (bash on Ubuntu 12.04). However the following

```
sed 's/string/\n/g'
```

does replace all occurrences of `string` by a line break.

For instance, consider the following `file`

```
hello
there
```

`sed 's/\n/ /g' file` gives me the same:

```
hello
there
```

but `sed 's/hello/hello\n/g' file` gives me a line break:

```
hello

there
```

Could some body tell me why `sed` is able to *write* a new line with `\n` but not to *read* it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` works on lines of input, you can't replace newlines like that.  You need to append *lines of input* to the pattern space.

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n/string/;ta' inputfile
```

would replace newlines with `string`.

Comment: That's why I would use a different tool :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n '1h;1!H;$x;s/\n/string/gp' YourFile
```

other method by loading first into buffer and change all at once at the end and print result